# Camera JNI. Manually set buffer was too small

Tags: android, android-camera

From an Android camera, I take YUV array and decode it to RGB. (JNI NDK) Then, I using black-white filter for RGB matrix, and show on CameraPrewiev in format YCbCr_420_SP

```
lParameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
```

Now I need to take a photo. But when I takePhoto, i have this error:

> CAMERA-JNI Manually set buffer was too small! Expected 1138126 bytes, but got 165888!

Comment: Could you please improve your question?

Comment: From android camera i take YUV array and decoding to RGB.(JNI NDK) Then, I using black-white filter for RGB matrix, and show on CameraPrewiev in format YCbCr_420_SP lParameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP); and... now i need take photo. But when I takePhoto, i have this error - 'CAMERA-JNI Manually set buffer was too small! Expected 1138126 bytes, but got 165888!'

Comment: Please add all the information to the original question.

Comment: Question is probably a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665843/android-camera-takepicture-is-using-previews-small-buffer?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because from Surface you are not give the image. You must give bitmap from layout and than save on SdCsrd in some folder as Compress JPG. Thanks for all. This question is closed.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the error described above, but it does not seem to be an actual solution to the problem.