# Android Camera takePicture is using Previews small buffer

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, android-camera

I am developing a project using OPENCV. I have some process on onCameraFrame. While it shows previews, user can take a photo. But in some devices, I take an error after called takePicture(...) method. What should I do?

```
E/Camera-JNI(11783): Manually set buffer was too small! Expected 539380 bytes, but got 460800!
```

new symptom: This buffer's size is my frame size, 460800. I logged frame size at onCameraFrame . Every frame's sizes are 460800.  As far as I understand, takePicture tries to use previews buffer. And theirs sizes are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I set the buffer size to match with the Picture Size. But with the preview, it started to show a ridiculous behavior like on some devices not to continue after taking the picture for the preview,... For this reason, When I push retake or back button, I close and restart the preview. It solves all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that kind of problem.
 It seems that on Android 2.2.1 you do have to set camera parameters BEFORE you call

```
camera.startPreview()
```

However on later systems like Android 3.2.1 this is no longer an issue (however it could be vendor specific).

Comment: I already set camera parameters.. :( If I set picture frame size half, it works. But I isn't right way.